# Dealing with detached dom elements, gridster.js plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am working with the gridster.js plugin, which is great, however it seems to be giving me issues when I am removing items using it's remove method. I am using its built in method called remove_all_widgets to wipe out what I currently have on the page and load in new content.

You can see it here.

```
 fn.remove_all_widgets = function(callback) {
    this.$widgets.each($.proxy(function(i, el){
          this.remove_widget(el, true, callback);
    }, this));

    return this;
};
```

It loops through the widgets and calls this remove_widget as seen here:

```
/**
* Remove a widget from the grid.
*
* @method remove_widget
* @param {HTMLElement} el The jQuery wrapped HTMLElement you want to remove.
* @param {Boolean|Function} silent If true, widgets below the removed one
* will not move up. If a Function is passed it will be used as callback.
* @param {Function} callback Function executed when the widget is removed.
* @return {Class} Returns the instance of the Gridster Class.
*/
fn.remove_widget = function(el, silent, callback) {
    var $el = el instanceof $ ? el : $(el);
    var wgd = $el.coords().grid;

    // if silent is a function assume it's a callback
    if ($.isFunction(silent)) {
        callback = silent;
        silent = false;
    }

    this.cells_occupied_by_placeholder = {};
    this.$widgets = this.$widgets.not($el);

    var $nexts = this.widgets_below($el);

    this.remove_from_gridmap(wgd);


    $el.fadeOut($.proxy(function() {

        $el.remove();

        if (!silent) {
            $nexts.each($.proxy(function(i, widget) {
                this.move_widget_up( $(widget), wgd.size_y );
            }, this));
        }

        this.set_dom_grid_height();

        if (callback) {
            callback.call(this, el);
        }
    }, this));

    return this;
};
```

I have small bits of javascript to run button functions and other assorted things. I realized soon after playing with it that it leaves the full html content of the widget in a detached dom tree thus keeping the js files running. I first found this because the buttons have the same names on new pages and it was running the click functions for both the newly loaded button and the one i had taken off the screen using gridsters remove_all_widgets method.

I can track the previous javascript to an (anonymous function) in chomes dev console, and within that i can see the entire html content inside of the detached tree. I am not refreshing the pages or anything, the new content is being brought in by ajax (I set ajax cache:false as well).

Is there any way around this? Would it be possible to clear the contents of the widgets before they get stuck like this? It would be ideal if it didn't happen at all or of there was some way to get rid of them completely when they get removed.

Thank you for taking the time to read this, any insight would be greatly helpful.

As per requests her is some of the code, the click functions on the lines button for example is double firing:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $(document).on("change",".accountContries",function(e){
    var countryPck =  $("body > .addAccountForm1").find(".accountContries").find('option:selected').attr('id');

 $.ajax(    
        {
         cache: false,
         url : "/listStates/" + countryPck,
         type : "GET",
         beforeSend: function(){
             $("body").append("<div class='loadingNow'></div>");
          }, 
          success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            $('.loadingNow').remove();     
            $(".accountStates").empty();
            $(".accountStates").append("<option value='' selected disabled> Select a State</option>");
            $.each(data.states, function(){
                $(".accountStates").append("<option value=" + this.id  +" id=" + this.id + ">" + this.name +"</option>");

            });

        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            errorOffScreen("List States by account");
        }
    });
});
 $(document).on("touchend click", ".lines-button", function(e){
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    if($(this).hasClass("close")){
        $(this).removeClass("close");
        $(".widget1x1Back").next(".actionsHolder3").slideUp("fast", function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });             
    }else{

        var iconsList = $(this).closest(".top1x1").next(".hdnActnLst").find(".iconsHolder3").html();
        $(this).closest(".widget1x1").append(iconsList);
        $(this).closest(".widget1x1").find(".actionsHolder3").hide();
            $(this).closest(".widget1x1").find(".actionsHolder3").slideDown(700,"easeOutBack");
        $(this).addClass("close");
    }
});

});
  </script>
```

UPDATE : it seems I only the stuff inside the `<Script>` tag is being kept even after the elements are .removed

Comment: How are you connecting your event handlers for the buttons etc? If you use delegated handlers it will only catch events in the document. Can you show your "small bits of javascript"?

Comment: via a script tag at the bottom of the html content, so it can pull in individually with the html content itself. I added some for example. Thanks!

Comment: The only event shown is already a delegated `on`, applied to the `document` element. By definition it cannot be applied to disconnected DOM elements that are not in the document. Got any more code to help identify some other issue?

Comment: What would be most helpful to see? I believe it is the way gridster handles the remove, the old html content is still lingering somewhere and firing. When i track the old javascript i can see it as  (anonymous function) in something called VM96 (the number changes). If i open that up in the console it is literally the whole  html content i am pulling in so it is somewhere, I can't tell where, or for that matter why gridster keeps it.

Comment: Sorry edit here - I can only see everything inside the <script> tags, not the html content

Comment: Based on your comments, you have code within the loaded pages that executes. If so, you will be registering new delegated `on` events each time you load a panel. It is your code that needs to behave, not a failure of the `remove`. Remove your code from the content and place it in the master page.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments and updates, you have Javascript in the loaded content pages. As that includes the use of delegated event handlers, that code will live on.

This is one case were you would be better off with normal non-delegated event handlers like:

```
$(".lines-button").bind("touchend click", function(e){
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
```

These bindings will terminate when the elements are removed (as they are *per-element* handlers).

*An alternative is to not have any code in the content pages, but only in the master page, and apply code as required when loading new content.*